# Using MySQL Query Cache and Memcached at the same time

Tags: mysql, performance, caching, memcached, query-cache

I think they are both great and I wanna know is it possible to use both caching systems together at the same time?
Is there any experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysqls working set will always be cached.

This is called double caching and represents a major bottleneck in larger systems (Facebook for example), where user data is double cached, existing twice in RAM.